# C# program exits immediately if UseWPF/UseWindowsForms set to true

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

The program:

```
Public Class QueryExecutor
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter y");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "y") return;
    }
}
```

The old .csproj. This causes the program to correctly ask for input in a console window.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The new .csproj. This causes the program to exit without opening a console.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The output from the new .csproj:

```
'TFSHygiene.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.9\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'TFSHygiene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\Nathan_Dehnel\source\repos\TFSHygiene\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\TFSHygiene.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TFSHygiene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.9\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'TFSHygiene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.9\System.Console.dll'. 
'TFSHygiene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.9\System.Threading.dll'. 
'TFSHygiene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.9\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
The program '[31740] TFSHygiene.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: If your entrypoint class is called `Blah` (and not `Program`), you may have some problems because with the new language features, you can actually have an empty project because a class `Program` with a `Main` method is created implicitly (and empty). Make sure your entrypoint class is called `Program`

Comment: Can you paste the actual code? `Public Class` won't compile, I suspect there may be other differences. Can you shorten your code down to a [mcve] that exhibits the problem?

Comment: The `WinExe` output type doesn't have a console so you can't read from it. The "old" project file is correct for what you're trying to do. It looks like you used the wrong project template.

Comment: I just tried Exe as well as netcoreapp3.1 and they both had the same problem. Looks like WPF/WindowsForms are the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking change in `.NET 5`.

[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/automatically-infer-winexe-output-type#outputtype-set-to-winexe-for-wpf-and-winforms-apps):

> `OutputType` is automatically set to `WinExe` for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Windows Forms apps. When `OutputType` is set to `WinExe`, a console window doesn't open when the app is executed.
>
> (...)
>
> ### Recommended action
>
> No action is required in your part. However, if you want to revert to the old behavior, set the `DisableWinExeOutputInference` property to `true` in your project file.
>
> ```
> <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
> ```

Your app is quitting because there is no standard input to use `ReadLine()` on.